# monitoring a range of cells inside of excel 2007 with C#/VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, data-binding, vsto, office-2007

I have a row in excel I'd like to translate into an ObserveableCollection in C# for binding/event purposes, so all accessor classes know they're getting the latest data from the source excel sheet. How would this be done?

Clarification: I'm using an excel add-in project, not a workbook project, so am not sure whether or not XMLMappedRange Controls are an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using VSTO you have a few options:

1. From the [Excel.Worksheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.aspx)  class, you can access the [Worksheet.Change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.change.aspx) event.

   From the [NamedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.aspx) class, you can access the [NamedRange.Change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.change.aspx) event (which uses the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler delegate that you mentioned in another comment).

   The NamedRange class also supports simple, one-way databinding via the [DataBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.tools.office.remotebindablecomponent.databindings.aspx) property, an example of which is shown in the discussion [How do I bind an array to a NamedRange](http://thedotnet.com/nntp/428906/showpost.aspx).

   Another possibility is the [XmlMappedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w9a2ck2.aspx) control, which also supports databinding.

A good primer on using the NamedRange and XmlMappedRange can be found here: [The VSTO Programming Model](http://www.devx.com/assets/download/14091.pdf). A decent walkthrough using the NamedRange can be found in the [Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) 2005 Guided Tour](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/downloads/timhuckaby/teched2006/Huckaby%20VSTO%202005%20Guided%20Tour.doc).

I hope this helps...

Mike

Comment: No problem, glad it helped, Daniel. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add OnChanged in your range changed event.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you be a bit more specific? I'm using an add-in, not a Workbook project. What assembly would I access the range changed event through?

Comment: I see Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler but am not sure if that's what you meant since it seems like it's a document-level handler and not a range-level.